# xcodebuild command fails building for device since upgrade to Xcode 6.1

Tags: ios, xcode6, xcodebuild, xcode6.1

I cannot build my project for the device although `XCode` can build without any issue given the same settings.

Here is the build command:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace /path/to/workspace/myProject.xcworkspace -scheme myScheme -configuration Debug -destination id=myDeviceIdentifier build
```

Here is the error i get:

```
xcodebuild: error: The run destination [device name] is not valid for Running the scheme 'myScheme'.
[device name] doesn't match any of myProject.app's targeted device families. You can expand myProject.app's targeted device families to support [device name].
```

I did check the targeted device family for the project and all of the subprojects, and it is fine.

The problem appears less often after removing a significant count of file references from the project.

Did some of you encounter the same issue and do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i could bypass the issue by debugging as universal app, although i am developing for ipad.

this changes `TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY` from `2` *(iPad)* to `"1,2"` *(Universal)* in the project file *(`project.pbxproj`)*.

---

there's also a quite simple way to reproduce the issue:

if you create two projects from template. one will work one not.

WORKS: Single View App, Objective C, Universal
DOES NOT WORK: Single View App, Objective C, iPad

more information can be found here:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-11204
- http://openradar.appspot.com/20526470

please file this issue with apple: http://bugreport.apple.com

Answer (score 0):

Try this steps:

- Go to Targets -> Valid Architectures & remove arm64
- Set Build active Architectures to No

Answer (score 0):

there might be another workaround by enabling a lot of debug output.

add the following parameter to the command:

`xcodebuild …`**`-IDERunDestinationLogLevel=3`**

somehow if log level 3 is set, building works. with log level 2 it does not.